# How to explain usage of past perfect in this case

Tags: past-perfect

I am having a hard time to understand the usage of past perfect in the following excerpt

> Deep in the bowels of the anchored vessel The Mendacium, facilitator Knowlton sat alone in his cubicle and tried in vain to focus on his work. **Filled** with trepidation, he had gone back to viewing the video and, for the past hour, had been analyzing the nine-minute soliloquy that hovered somewhere between genius and madness.

Shouldn't it say

> Deep in the bowels of the anchored vessel The Mendacium, facilitator Knowlton sat alone in his cubicle and tried in vain to focus on his work. **He had been filled** with trepidation and had gone back to viewing the video and, for the past hour, had been analyzing the nine-minute soliloquy that hovered somewhere between genius and madness.

The reasoning is First he was filled with "trepidation" then he viewed the video and then he was sitting alone in his cubicle.

The original paragraph makes me feel that he was sitting willed with trepidation because before that he viewed the video.

Comment: *Filled* here is a past participle used in an absolute construction to modify the subject of the following independent clause, the verb of that clause, or as a complement to the whole thing.  It is a non-finite verb form, meaning that it does not carry tense at all.  It's not an example of the past perfect

Comment: Any other examples of such kind?

Comment: An example of the past perfect and past perfect progressive follows imediately:  "He had gone back to viewing....had been analyzing the nine-minute....."

Comment: It's fairly common.  Consider: ***Striking** a pose, she let the photographer snap her picture.*  In this case, it's the present participle *striking*, which is different from a progressive tense of the verb to strike.

Comment: Thanks for the examples but but examples in past tenses?

Answer (score -1):

He was still filled with trepidation. Past Perfect would mean he wasn't filled with trepidation any more.

Comment: Certainly it means that he was filled with trepidation when he went back to view the video.  How long the trepidation appeared before or lasted after the going back is unknown.  See my comment above.  *Filled* is a participle here and doesn't carry tense.